# example for builder property in MaterialApp class in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In MaterialApp class, there is a property call builder.

Are there any example or tutorial on how to use the builder property?

Comment: What do you need an example for? `builder: (context, widget) => new Container(child: widget),`

Comment: I dont understand what it is used for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`builder` property is used to override properties implicitly set by `MaterialApp`, such as `Navigator`, `MediaQuery` or internationalization.

For example, one could want to override `Navigator` with a custom made one for custom route transitions:

```
MaterialApp(
 builder: (_, __) {
   return Navigator(
     // TODO: add custom transition
   );
 }
);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more how to implement the MyAuth? I want to have a widget that handle log in/out, I am using the build method and creating a widget, but when I try to navigate using MyAuth I got the following error:

Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

Comment: @<Guilherme Torres Castro> You must get navigator state from child widget like that  (child.key as GlobalKey<NavigatorState>).currentState  and do the push or pop on currentState

Comment: Please elaborate the example.. in a real scenario

Comment: can u please give me an example on how to use two functions like MediaQuery and internationalization in the same builder

Answer (score 22):

#### `builder` can be used to wrap your route-widgets with a parent widget.

For example, if you have a `LoadingSpinner` widget, then instead of wrapping every single route widget in it. You can simple do:

```
builder: (context, widget) => LoadingSpinner(child: widget)
```

And `widget` would be whatever widget you have in that specific route.

#### Localization use case

Another useful use case is if you have top level BLoCs (such as a login BLoC) that require a language:

```
   MaterialApp(
        //... All the config properties
        builder: (context, widget) => Provider<LoginBloc>(
              // This line has access to the Locales
              builder: (_) => LoginBloc(languageCode: Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode),
              dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
              child: widget, // `widget` is either ProfilePage or LoginPage`
            ),
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en', 'US'), // US English
          const Locale('en', 'GB'), // GB English
          const Locale('da', 'DK'), // Danish
          // ... other locales the app supports
        ],
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/profile': (context) => ProfilePage(),
          '/login': (context) => LoginPage(),
        },
      ),
    );
```

If you were to place the `Provider` as a parent to `MaterialApp`, `Localizations.localeOf(context)` would crash. So here the builder shows it's value.

*The above assumes you know what the BLoC pattern is, and what a `Provider` is.*